# Is there any cross-browser solution for accessing Activex objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, activex

We have a Classic ASP application that uses Activex object (javascript) for connecting with backend. This does not work with Chrome, Safari and Firefox. Is there any alternate approach available?

Comment: r u trying to do an ajax call?

Comment: ActiveX is an Internet-Explorer-only technology as it's developed by microsoft (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX), so it won't ever work in other browsers. Please try to give a bit more information so we can try to find an alternative solution for you.

Comment: We are not trying to make ajax call. We are looking for alternate solution for conventional way of creating ADODB.Connection, ADODB.Recordset objects to connect with backend from asp pages. The solution should work with chrome, Safari, firefox and IE 9 browsers. Thanks for your response.

Comment: There's no alternate solution that'll allow you to make connections to your database from those other browsers on Windows or non-Windows operating systems, or at least nothing short of writing complete applications that could be installed on target platforms by willing end users.

Comment: @Kamalraj Are you sure you are using `ADODB.Connection` and Recordset from the *client side*? Usually those things are used in server-side script, at which point browsers don't care about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this library:

http://jquery.com/

It has a function:

jQuery.ajax(settings);

Documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

using ADODB in the none IE browsers can't be done as you correctly asked it is an ActiveX control, and it's a nasty ActiveX control you would be best looking at using jQuery as @emphaticsunshine posted with out giving any link to your question,

and a server side file for managing the data on the server environment and use your server todo it, if i remember correctly MS are pulling ActiveX in one of the next browsers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and we implemented the following solution using CORS, WCF, Windows Service, IE Process. Here's the brief:

You host a wcf service in a windows service in which you open a hidden IE process to open a html page which in turn calls the activeX and gets the data from it.
If you can access the activeX object(dll) directly from C# then you dont need to use hidden IE approach. In my case this wasn't possible.

You call this wcf service from your website page (javascript) using CORS(cross origin), you can use different approaches for it CORS,JsonP etc. For me CORS worked best. You can also implement web socket for this and expose socket from your above window service.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Emulate the XMLHttpRequest() constructor in IE5 and IE6
if (window.XMLHttpRequest === undefined) {
window.XMLHttpRequest = function() {
try {
// Use the latest version of the ActiveX object if available
return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
}
catch (e1) {
try {
// Otherwise fall back on an older version
return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
}
catch(e2) {
// Otherwise, throw an error
throw new Error("XMLHttpRequest is not supported");
}
}
};
}
```

//the definitive guide to js prescribes this approach. use XMLHttpRequest and if the client doesnt have a window.XMLHttpRequest, figure out what it needs and feed it that. 
---good luck